# Auto calculation wont run using Application-function

Tags: vba, excel

I got sheets that are with OLAP-connections and I found a VBA that loops through selected folder. To get the loop "wait" I have added `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone`.

For some reason other sheets don't calculate OLAP-values unless I add `Application.CalculateFull` or `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` or of course `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`.

I cant find a solution to it, or any reason to why this should happen so I hope you lot could point my errors ;)